# Display flex align to left

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to align `<div class="Text">Some text</div>` to left?

```css
    .navigation {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80px;
        background: rgb(255,255,255);
    }
    ul {
        list-style:none;
        /*float:right;*/
    }
    li {
        display:inline-block;
    }
    a {
        padding: 10px;
        width: 80px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    a:hover{
        background:lightgreen;
    }
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
    <div class="Text">Some text</div> 
    <ul>
        <li><a>Contacts</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a>Other</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also just use `justify-content: space-between` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/916/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.Text {
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet

```
.Text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```